# Undo automounting my second internal HDD at boot

Tags: boot, mount, automount

When I installed 12.04, I let Ubuntu automount my second internal HDD at boot. Now I formatted it and now it says "/media/Dateien isn't ready to mount" at boot. By clicking 'S' I can normally continue booting. But I don't want to have to click 'S' every time I'm booting. How can I undo it that Ubuntu searches for this HDD at boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: be careful in performing the steps below. Doing it wrong may cause further issues. Since there's no *good* and user friendly GUI to do this properly (PySDM is removed!), here are steps to do it the manual way:

1. Start a Terminal.
2. Make a backup of the file we're about to edit.

   ```
   cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab-backup
   ```
3. Open `/etc/fstab` with your favourite editor, but do this with elevated privileges, e.g.:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   to open Gedit with this file and proper root privileges.
4. Locate the line with your hard disk and its mount point. This should be a *single* line. For **example**:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/crypt-homes /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   ```
5. Once you're sure this is the line, remove it. Don't touch others.
6. Save and close the editor.
7. I *think* you should also update the initramfs, responsible for finding the devices in the boot process. This is harmless anyway.

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   That may take a few seconds.
8. Reboot.

Comment: the errors you're talking about, are these errors inside ubuntu or are these errors that affect the hdd

Comment: @Masrepus Configuration errors in `/etc/fstab` may cause an unbootable system, but don't *break* anything as in losing data, but it may be hard to get it running again. And then, your question in itself is about such an error which is recoverable as you explained already, but other errors may not be and drop you out of the boot process. I've rephrased the "errors" part now. :)

Comment: UUID=57de8691-3b25-46c9-9f86-30f03daadbc2 /media/Dateien  ext4    defaults        0       2 --this may be the line in my case, I think?